# Call a javascript class object with variable

Tags: javascript, object, scope

I am new to Object Orientated Javascript and have created an object called Foo (based on a class) with an object called buttons. To call buttons I can type

```
console.log('foo log: ',foo.buttons)
//foo log:  testButton1
```

I want to replace call foo.buttons by replacing foo with a variable called **`myVar`**. It must be simple but none of the solutions I can see for this seem to work in my situation. I think there may be a scope problem but don't understand what it is.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED ALREADY

```js
class TestClass {
  constructor(
    button)
    {this.button = button}
}

const myVar = 'foo'
const foo = new TestClass ('testButton1')

console.log('foo log: ', foo.button)
//foo log:  testButton1

console.log('myVar: ', myVar)
//foo




console.log('Attempt1: ', [myVar].button)
//Attempt1:  undefined

//console.log('Attempt2: ', [myVar]button)
//     failed to compile

console.log('Attempt3: ', myVar.button)
//Attempt3:  undefined

console.log('Attempt4: ', (myVar).button)
//Attempt4:  undefined

console.log('this:', this)
```

Comment: "*I want to replace call foo.buttons by replacing foo with a variable called myVar*" - why?

Comment: If you declare it as a global variable using `var` you could use `window[myVar]`. As long as your scope is `window` or whatever you assing it to.

Comment: I have a prop that is comming from another component and I want that prop myVar to be used to find the object that relates to it so I can use that in the program later on

Comment: I don't know who closed it, so I can't give a proper answer.
In my opinion, best approach would be to map your cases.

Something like:
```const options = { foo: new TestClass('testButton1'), bar: new TestClass('testButton2'), baz: new TestClass('testButton3') }
```.


Then you get it with ```options[myVar].button```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), but this could be dangerous.

```js
class TestClass {
  constructor(
    button)
    {this.button = button}
}

const myVar = 'foo'
const foo = new TestClass ('testButton1')

console.log(eval(myVar).button)
```

Comment: thanks! I looked up eval and it says using strings to invoke object is a bad idea. This will get me by for the moment but I'll look into alternative was of achieving my aim. Thanks